# Wordpress video js error this.mediaElement.play is not a function

Tags: plugin-development, video-player, wp-error

I am using the video.js library in WordPress it causes an error (ERROR: TypeError: this.mediaElement.play is not a function) since I have installed themify builder plugin. Error picture attached. Can anyone help me to get out of this error?

[image]

Comment: You'll have to open a ticket with the Themify.me support staff.  Third Party plugins and themes are off topic and you really shouldn't be editing their code, so get their support team on the case.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

we can't tell much from this screenshot apart that you've indeed installed video.js (at least part of it).
this is a big guess but i would say that the lib tries to get your media element by id, but the id being wrong it doesn't have access to a play method, most i can do to help is to suggest you to [refer to the doc](https://videojs.com/getting-started).